# How to convert hex to string of hex

Tags: perl

I have a problem understanding and using the 'vec' keyword.

I am reading a logpacket in which values are stored in little endian hexadecimal. In my code, I have to unpack the different bytes into scalars using the [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) keyword.

Here's an example of my problem:

```
my @hexData1 = qw(50 65);
my $data = pack ('C*', @hexData1);
my $x = unpack("H4",$data);    # At which point the hexadecimal number became a number 
print $x."\n";
#my $foo = sprintf("%x", $foo);

print "$_-> " . vec("\x65\x50", $_, 1) . ", " for (0..15);    # This works.
print "\n";
```

But I want to use the above statement in the way below. I don't want to send a string of hexadecimal in quotes. I want to use the scalar array of hex $x. But it won't work. How do I convert my $x to a hexadecimal string. This is my requirement.

```
print "$_-> " . vec($x, $_, 1).", " for (0..15);    # This doesn't work.
print "\n";
```

My final objective is to read the third bit from the right of the two byte hexadecimal number.

How do I use the 'vec' command for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making the mistake of `unpack`ing $data into `$x` before using it in a call to `vec`. `vec` expects a string, so if you supply a number it will be converted to a string before being used. Here's your code

```
my @hexData1 = qw(50 65);
my $data= pack ('C*', @hexData1);
```

The `C` `pack` format uses each value in the source list as a character code. It is the same as calling `chr` on each value and concatenating them. Unfortunately your values look like decimal, so you are getting `chr(50).chr(65)` or `"2A"`. Since your values are little-endian, what you want is `chr(0x65).chr(0x50)` or `"\x65\x50"`, so you must write

```
my $data= pack ('(H2)*', reverse @hexData1);
```

which reverses the list of data (to account for it being little-endian) and packs it as if it was a list of two-digit hex strings (which, fortunately, it is).

Now you have done enough. As I say, `vec` expects a string so you can write

```
print join ' ', map vec($data, $_, 1), 0 .. 15;
print "\n";
```

and it will show you the bits you expect. To extract the *the 3rd bit from the right* (assuming you mean bit 13, where the last bit is bit 15) you want

```
print vec $data, 13, 1;
```

Comment: `reverse` won't work when he has more than two bytes like he said he did in a comment to another post.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the number the bytes represent.

If you start with "\x50\x65",

```
my $num = unpack('v', "\x50\x65");
```

If you start with "5065",

```
my $num = unpack('v', pack('H*', "5065"));
```

If you start with "50","65",

```
my $num = unpack('v', pack('H*', join('', "50","65"));
```

---

Then, extract the bit you want.

If you want bit 10,

```
my $bit = ($num >> 10) & 1;
```

If you want bit 2,

```
my $bit = ($num >> 2) & 1;
```

---

(I'm listing a few possibilities because it's not clear to me what you want.)

Comment: I want to learn how to use 'vec' keyword. I also don't know how to unpack into a string format into a scalar from the $data. Also, the original data is not in string format, and hence, you cannot use "\x50\x65". Like I said in my code, I get what I want when I use "\x65\x50" inside the 'vec' keyword in quotes. I want to use 'vec' and want to pass a scalar or a variable that contains the actual string without quotes. Thanks!

Comment: So you're starting with `"5065"` then? Don't tell me what it's not, tell me what it is! (I'm not posting four more guesses. You're going to be clear before I continue.)

Comment: You said "it's not in string format" and you said "it's little-endian". Those are contradictory statements.

Comment: @ikegami: presumably the OP means the data isn't in *packed* string format, so the source looks like `"xxx 50 65 xxx"` rather than `"\x50\x65"`

Comment: @Borodin, That's a possibility, and I've already asked him to confirm that.

Comment: Yes, its not in a packed string format. Also, they are in little endian format

Comment: @Fighter2, Added code for `"50","65"` as a starting input, so now you know how to do it starting with any of `$x`, `$data` and `@hexData1`.

Comment: @Fighter2, `my @nums = unpack 'v*', pack 'C*', map hex, split ' ', '50 65 0F 1A';`

Comment: @Fighter2, "little-endian" makes no sense unless you also specify "16-bit" or "32-bit". Use `v` for 16-bit and `V` for 32-bit